# Get next alphabet of a character

Tags: swift

Is there any specific API to get the next alphabet of a character?

Example:

> if `"Somestring".characters.first` results in `"S"`, then should
>   return `"T"`

If there's none I guess I have to iterate through a collection of alphabet and return the next character in order. Or is there any other better solution?

Comment: Probably you should get the next iteration by character's ASCII value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you think of the Latin capital letters "A" ... "Z" then the
following should work:

```
func nextLetter(_ letter: String) -> String? {

    // Check if string is build from exactly one Unicode scalar:
    guard let uniCode = UnicodeScalar(letter) else {
        return nil
    }
    switch uniCode {
    case "A" ..< "Z":
        return String(UnicodeScalar(uniCode.value + 1)!)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

It returns the next Latin capital letter if there is one,
and `nil` otherwise. It works because the Latin capital letters
have consecutive Unicode scalar values.
(Note that `UnicodeScalar(uniCode.value + 1)!` cannot fail in that
range.) The `guard` statement handles both multi-character
strings and extended grapheme clusters (such as flags "").

You can use

```
    case "A" ..< "Z", "a" ..< "z":
```

if lowercase letters should be covered as well.

Examples:

```
nextLetter("B") // C
nextLetter("Z") // nil
nextLetter("€") // nil
```

Comment: Note also that we may capture the _"check if string is built from exactly one unicode scalar"_ logic with a single call to the failable [`UnicodeScalar` by `String` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unicodescalar/2430716-init), upon which we could apply a `flatMap` containing a single ternary evaluation (for the pattern matching), conditionally returning the next letter `String`. E.g., for really no good reason at all reducing the body above to: `return UnicodeScalar(letter).flatMap { "A"..<"Z" ~= $0 ? String(UnicodeScalar($0.value + 1)!) : nil }`

Comment: ... the `UnicodeScalar` initializer [seemingly does exactly the same job](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/UnicodeScalar.swift#L285) for us as is performed explicitly above (I just wonder why they'd use `description` as internal name, as that usually is a red flag for explicit usage for me).

Comment: @dfri: Excellent suggestion! (But I'll keep the switch/case for clarity :)

Comment: Yes the ternary approach is a bit too much, and falls apart in case we want to use matching over two patterns (`"A" ..< "Z", "a" ..< "z"`). Although the switch/case can be quite neatly wrapped in the `flatMap` call as another alternative to the above, if case we'd like to combine the `nil` returns of failed initialization and failed pattern matching rather than being explicit about it :) Now over and out!

Answer (score 5):

```
func nextChar(str:String) {
    if let firstChar = str.unicodeScalars.first {
        let nextUnicode = firstChar.value + 1
        if let var4 = UnicodeScalar(nextUnicode) {
            var nextString = ""
            nextString.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(var4)))
            print(nextString)
        }
    }
}
nextChar(str: "A")  // B
nextChar(str: "ζ")  // η
nextChar(str: "z")  // {
```

Comment: I cannot accept both answers but because I didn't specify that I only accept Latin letters in the question so I upvote your answer in return. Cheers.